# Does navigation to a site NOT from google increase its ranking in google search?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

Let's stay I have a website with the link www.example.com If I navigate directly to this website, not from google, will it google search ranking increase? Or do I have to enter this website from a google search engine, to increase its rank? Let's say I have registered and verified this website in google search console application.

Comment: ***Does navigation to a site NOT from google increase its ranking in google search?*** Short answer. No.

Comment: @closetnoc can you please explain why? or atleast clarify your answer about what tou mean as no

Comment: Navigating to a site has no influence on ranking. Links do affect ranking, but mainly for the site linked to. Going to a site from Google has no effect on ranking.